# BMP280 temperature reading between arduino library and datasheet are different

Tags: sensors, esp32, temperature, adafruit

I'm using a [BMP280](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP280-DS001-11.pdf) to measure the **temperature**. These are the values that I get from the **BMP280**.

| Var | Value |
| --- | --- |
| dig_T1 | 0x6B51 |
| dig_T2 | 0x684B |
| dig_T3 | 0xFC18 |
| ADC_T | 0x819F0 |

This table follows from my **logic analyzer**
[Dig_T# data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moA6i.jpg) [Temp Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNbCi.jpg)

With these values the temperature should be **35.20°C** according the **datasheet**. On the bosch website there's an [example](https://community.bosch-sensortec.com/t5/MEMS-sensors-forum/BME280-Temperature-Compensation-Issue/td-p/7742?attachment-id=1368) that confirms this. However using the [**Adafruit BMP280 Library**](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP280_Library) these values result in a temperature of **28.36°C**. I'm running this library on my esp32-S2.

Which of these values is the right one?

Comment: What does a thermometer say?

Comment: The thermometer says 23°C so it’s all a little off.

Comment: 12C is way more than a little bit…

Comment: the 5C from the adafruit library is also more than i would expect.